# how to set a place holder to widgets in a sign up view (forms.PasswordInput()) Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to give my {{form.password1}} a placeholder.

```
#The concept is like this:
<input type="password" placeholder="password">
```

I tried to do in django using django and this is my sign up form:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms

class CreateUser(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1', 'password2']
        widgets = {
            'username' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'username', 'placeholder':'Username'}),
            'email' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email'}),
            'password1' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Password'}),
            'password2' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Confirm Your Password'}),
        }
```

But It doesn't show the password1 and password2 placeholders
This is my register.html:

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div>{{form.username}}</div>
        <div>{{form.email}}</div>
        <div>{{form.password1}}</div>
        <div>{{form.password2}}</div>
        <input type="submit" placeholder="Register">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually answered my question, which is I guess the best answer, It is by using **Django Tweaks**
You first need to install Django Tweaks from the terminal using:

```
pip3 install django-widget-tweaks #on linux and mac
pip install django-widget-tweaks # on windows
```

Then you need to add it to settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .....
    'widget_tweaks',
    .....
]
```

Than you need to do this in your html file:

```html
{% load widget-tweaks %}
{% render_field your_form.your_field class="your class" placeholder="your placeholder" ... %}
# like that you can put any attr you want
```

Hope you like it. And hope it may help you.
**Check this if you still don't get it** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYs-u0g__1A